# .NET Charting 4.0 -- make line instead of bar

Tags: .net, charts

```
var pointCollection = lastValuation.ValuationExposureCollection[lastValuation.ValuationExposureCollection.Count - 1].ExposurePointCollection;

                System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart Chart2 = new System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart();
                Chart2.Width = 350;
                Chart2.Height = 350;
                Chart2.RenderType = RenderType.ImageTag;

                Chart2.Palette = ChartColorPalette.BrightPastel;
                Chart2.ChartAreas.Add("Series 1");
                Chart2.ChartAreas["Series 1"].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;

                // create a couple of series  
                Chart2.Series.Add("Series");

                // databinding
                Chart2.DataSource = pointCollection;
                Chart2.Series[0].XValueMember = "ExposureDate";
                Chart2.Series[0].XValueType = ChartValueType.Date;
                Chart2.Series[0].YValueMembers = "MaximumExposure";


                Chart2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(211, 223, 240); //"#D3DFF0"
                Chart2.BorderSkin.SkinStyle = BorderSkinStyle.Emboss;
                Chart2.BackGradientStyle = GradientStyle.TopBottom;

                // Render chart control  
                Chart2.Page = this;

                Page.Response.Clear();

                HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(Page.Response.Output);
                Chart2.RenderControl(writer);
```

This is my current chart. How do I turn this into a line graph instead of a bar chart? Also, is there a way to make one of the points in the line chart bolded out as like a more noticeable point for an important value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the chart type via the Series object's [`ChartType` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.series.charttype.aspx):

```
Chart2.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
```

Comment: Do you know how I could put a label for both the Y and X axis?

Comment: @slandau: You specify the label values when plotting the points. I don't see where you're doing that. Might I suggest you check out my article on using the Microsoft Chart Controls? http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/072209-1.aspx

Comment: Very nice. But those seem like labels per point of plotting data, I just need two labels. One telling what each axis is